# Inline JavaScript Validation Not Work

Tags: javascript, html, inline

I tried to validate some input like this.but this not work..what is the correct way **without using external JS or external method...**

```
<input type='number' class='form-control input-sm' onkeypress="return this.value < = 100;">
```

Comment: Use `max` attribute ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-max))

Comment: but this is working fine.! above code is not work!

    <input type='number' class='form-control input-sm' onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">

Comment: cannot use max attribute according to my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `keypress` use `onkeyup`.

```
<input type='number' class='form-control input-sm'
 onkeyup="this.value =(this.value <= 100) ? this.value : '';">
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xdzakmzf/)